# How do I redirect a specific page on my drupal site to an external site?

Tags: redirection

I have a shop on my drupal website which we have replaced with an updated squarespace page.  I need the drupal page to automatically redirect to the new shop and I can only find a help page from circa '07 which says redirects are in the works...
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Drupal you are using?

Comment: You could do it at the server level or use hook_init(), check the URL and use drupal_goto(). Doing it with nginx or Apache would be best in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal_goto("external-path");

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to redirect automatically,

1) Web Server, Apache or nginx: in Apache, you can write rewrite rules() [this link will help](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/htaccess-redirect.htm) in .htaccess file which you can place in your document root. In nginx you can follow [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx)

2) Drupal hooks: hook_init or hook_boot, check the page URL using `drupal_get_path_alias(current_path())` and use [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x)

3) javascript or jquery -> Add js to the respective page which you needs to redirect

Using Jquery: `$(location).attr('href',url);`

Using javascript: `window.location.href="url";`